# Geeting undefined referance to SSLv3-client-method while installing asterisk 1.8 on rasbian os

Tags: c, asterisk

For my task I need to install asterisk 1.8 on rasbian-os, but I'm facing SSLv3-client-method error on make.

I'm installing libssl1.0-dev package also for solution, but getting same issue.

```
 Warning:
[CC] tcptls.c -> tcptls.o
tcptls.c: In function ‘__ssl_setup’:
tcptls.c:347:4: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv3_client_method’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    cfg->ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv3_client_method());
    ^
tcptls.c:347:4: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/src/asterisk-1.8.21.0/include/asterisk/tcptls.h:59:0,
                 from tcptls.c:44:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:2131:10: note: expected ‘const struct SSL_METHOD *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
 SSL_CTX *SSL_CTX_new(const SSL_METHOD *meth);


Error:
tcptls.o: In function `__ssl_setup':
/usr/src/asterisk-1.8.21.0/main/tcptls.c:347: undefined reference to `SSLv3_client_method'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:183: recipe for target 'asterisk' failed
make[1]: *** [asterisk] Error 1
Makefile:348: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 2
```

Comment: Can you include more version information? Which version of raspbian? Where are you getting the asterisk source from?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is always same and multiple times answered.

1.8 not supported anymore, so nobody add #defines to support NEW openssl libs.
Use older libs or current asterisk

Comment: thank you @arheops, it got solved using libssl version 1.0.0